# How to stop range slider at a certain point before maximum?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, html-input

I am using angularjs to stop range slider at 75 but its not a good way plus not working exactly. Can some body guide me how to do it?  **Remember** I do want to show total 100 or maximum scale but still want to limit to 75 percent or at 75. So dont tell me to use `max` attribute.

```
<html ng-app="root">
<body>
<div ng-controller="index">{{message}}
    <input type=range ng-model="data.sl" id=sl />
    <input type=text ng-model="data.sl" />
</div>
</body>
</html>
<script src="angular.js"></script>

angular.module('root', [])
.controller("index", ["$scope", function ($scope) {
$scope.message = "Hello World!";
$scope.data = {};
$scope.data.sl = 12;
$scope.$watch('data.sl',function(nv,ov){
    if(nv==ov)return;

    if(nv >= 75){
        document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
        console.log("going up");
    }
});
}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here I go:

```
        $scope.$watch('data.sl',function(nv,ov){
        if(nv==ov)return;

        if(nv >= 75){
            //document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
            $scope.data.sl=75;
            console.log("going up");
        }
        if(nv <= 25){
            //document.getElementById("sl").stepDown(10);
            $scope.data.sl=25;
            console.log("going down");
        }
    });
```